# Text doesn't break in special case

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, line-breaks

I have a problem that the text doesn't break in a popup made with Vue.js which is included in the header like this:

[image]

The text breaks normally if I include the popup into the main screen, but doesn't if I include it into the header. I have also drawn border around the <p> element which contains the text and the border is drawn correctly.

Here is the sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-feather-3zi3d?file=/src/components/BasicModal.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class .header-frame is adding the css:

```
.header-frame {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This is the reason for which the text does not break when inside the header.

Try adding

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

or

```
white-space: initial;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you maybe know why would this line be in .header-frame class? I did not create this part of the code and I would like to understand if there is some reason why this would be there.

Comment: @mbostic You've put the modal inside the header component, and if you look at App.vue there is the styling for nowrap. You need to move the modal out of the header.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following style rule :

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

in :

```
<p slot="modal-paragraph" style="border-style: solid;whitespace:pre-wrap">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove :

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

from `header-frame` class

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you maybe know why would this line be in .header-frame class? I did not create this part of the code and I would like to understand if there is some reason why this would be there.